# typescript でencoding-japaneseでエラーしてしまう

Tags: typescript

node18を利用しているのですが、下記のコードでエラーが出てしまうのですが、どのように対応すればいいでしょうか。

**エラー:**

```
この呼び出しに一致するオーバーロードはありません。
  前回のオーバーロードにより、次のエラーが発生しました。
    型 'string | number[] | ArrayBuffer' の引数を型 'WithImplicitCoercion<string> | { [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "string"): string; }' のパラメーターに割り当てることはできません。
      型 'number[]' を型 'WithImplicitCoercion<string> | { [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "string"): string; }' に割り当てることはできません。
```

**コード:**

```
import * as enc from "encoding-japanese";

const RequestJson = queryString.parse(event.body, "&", "=", { decodeURIComponent: myDecodeURIComponent });

function myDecodeURIComponent(str: string): string {
  const decoded = enc.urlDecode(str);
  const encoded = enc.convert(decoded, {
    from: "SJIS",
    to: "UTF8"
  });
  
  const buf = Buffer.from(encoded);
  return buf.toString();
}
```